# How many session will create using single pool?

Tags: node.js, oracle, connection-pooling, knex.js

I am using `Knex` *version 0.21.15* npm. my pooling parameter is `pool` `{min: 3 , max:300}`.
Oracle is my data base server.

1. `pool` Is this pool count or session count?
2. If it is pool, how many sessions can create using a single pool?
3. If i run one non transaction query 10 time using knex connection ,how many sessions will create?
4. And when the created session will cleared from oracle session?
5. Is there any parameter available to remove the idle session from oracle.?

suggest me please if any.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING**: a pool.max value of 300 is **far too large.** You really don't want the database administrator running your Oracle server to distrust you: that can make your work life much more difficult.  And such a large max pool size can bring the Oracle server to its knees.

It's a paradox: often you can get better throughput from a database application by reducing the pool size. That's because many concurrent queries can clog the database system.

The `pool` object here governs how many connections may be in the pool at once. Each connection is a so-called *serially reusable resource.* That is, when some part of your nodejs program needs to run a query or series of queries, it grabs a connection from the pool. If no connection is already available in the pool, the pooling stuff in knex opens a new one.

If the number of open connections is already at the `pool.max` value, the pooling stuff makes that part of your nodejs program wait until some other part of the program finishes using a connection in the pool.

When your part of the nodejs program finishes its queries, it releases the connection back to the pool to be reused when some other part of the program needs it.

This is almost absurdly complex. Why bother?  Because it's expensive to open connections and much cheaper to re-use them.

Now to your questions:

> pool Is this pool count or session count?

It is a pair of limits (min / max) on the count of connections (sessions) open within the  pool at one time.

> If it is pool, how many sessions can create using a single pool?

Up to the pool.max value.

> If i run one non transaction query 10 time using knex connection ,how many sessions will create?

It depends on concurrency.  If your tenth query before the  first one completes, you may use ten connections from the pool. But you will most likely use fewer than that.

> And when the created session will cleared from oracle session?

As mentioned, the pool keeps up to pool.max connections open. That's why 300 is too  many.

> Is there any parameter available to remove the idle session from oracle.?

This operation is called "evicting" connections from the pool. knex does not support this.  Oracle itself may drop idle connections after a timeout. Ask your  DBA about that.

In the meantime, use the knex defaults of `pool: {min: 2, max: 10}` unless and until you really understand pooling and the required concurrency of your application. `max:300` would only be justified under very special circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your response .my application had 3000 users and i suspect 300+  concurrent users, need to run more parallel queries so that i set max `pool : 300`

Comment: You are making a big mistake when you set the pool size so high, even if you have that many concurrent users. Seriously. You want to serialize their access to the database, not run all their queries in parallel.

Comment: i get the connection and stored in memory,when the connection is required get the connection object from memory and execute the query.

Comment: query execution are seriously,but more user are there. More queries need to run single connection.

Comment: i reduced the mij and max pool size, some time i got the following error message. The pool is probably full.

Comment: Make sure to increase `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE `when you increase the pool size, see https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#numberofthreads  With `max` at 10 you need `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` to be 10 or greater. Note that Knex does not use node-oracledb's connection pool implementation so it won't benefit from some Oracle and node-oracledb high-availability features.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJones i understood the power of UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE. But how can handle idle connection detect and remove or reuse the connections in knex (oracle 19c)